# Topology Edge loop problem

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, subdivision-surface, topology, loop

How to solve this topology issue? I want the edge to be sharp but i dont want the sharpness on the surface.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following topology instead.....

[image]

If you use a Shrinkwrap to make the vertices stick to a cylinder, then move them a bit, you have almost no pinching. If it's still too much you need a cylinder with more vertices:

[image]

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/5k7nxG8/no2.png

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/Ptr4SPQ/no.png

Comment: You can see the problem is still kinda there, not entirely clean

Comment: use a shrinkwrap with another cylinder as target